# MySQL, possible to prevent two fields to be NULL or NOT NULL?

Tags: mysql, restriction, foreign-key

a simple table:

```
ID, NAME, POST_ID, GROUP_ID
```

either POST_ID or GROUP_ID must be set, but never both of them, NEITHER none of them. So,

there are valid cases:

```
ID, NAME, POST_ID, GROUP_ID
x,   y,   1,       NULL
x,   y,   NULL,    4
```

and NOT VALID cases:

```
ID, NAME, POST_ID, GROUP_ID
x,   y,   NULL,    NULL
x,   y,   4,       4
```

is it possible to set such complicated restriction rule?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. I would catch such cases in the front-end where the user enters the data. Also, you can perhaps replace both fields with two other fields:

A `category` field of type `enum` with possible values 'post' or 'group'
A `reference` field containing the ID.

That way you can easily demand both to be non-empty and you can only reference a post ID or a group ID.

Comment: And then you can't define an FK. That's why this should be on the DBA site.